# Questions about my electrical setup

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have an older home that has some weird (IMHO) setup and was hoping if someone more knowledgeable could shed some insight.

So I have a large electrical panel, about 30 inches in height, but it only has room for 8 circuit breakers (that is there are 8 pre-punched holes for circuit breakers in the panel).  Running off this panel was the irrigation system and well pump/water treatment system.  However, there is not a circuit breaker for the next panel which I will talk about later.  Turning off the large 200 amp CB at the top turns off power to the house, so I know this is the main panel.

So first it seems odd that such a large panel has such few places for circuit breakers.  Is this common?  Why would one do it this way?  Could this be expanded?  While there are not pre-punched holes it looks like main bars do extend past the last CB slot.

Next inside the house is a similarly sized panel but with a total of 30 pre-punched slots.  Is it odd that there is no CB between this panel and the main panel?

Then in the laundry room there is another sub panel.  This panel runs the air handler and air conditioner which is located in that room.  There is a 100 amp CB on the second panel for this sub panel.

Any thoughts is welcomed especially those directed at safety.  There were a lot of things I corrected myself or hired an electrician to correct that could caused a fire.  Those were done without delay.

Comment: Pictures of the panels will help.  Just too many different ones to go by size alone.  Some panels are fed by just lugs/wire connections with the breaker for it in another panel.

Comment: Get a good electrician in your area to investigate properly - a few pics (even though asked for by others on here) will only be a guess.

Comment: Connection of the second panel to the first would be a "main lug" connection - it's fine if the wires or cable are properly sized for the 200A feed, as the 200A breaker protects them. Pictures, particularly of the panel labelling (which may need to be with the covers off to get the important labelling - work with care) would be required to say anything more about the panels. Specific brand and model number information would be conveyed by that labelling.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Revise to ask a single, clear, specific question per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Novices should be very, very cautious about "fixing" things. A great many things *are* correct, but simply beyond your experience.  In a shabbily wired house, it can be a challenge to figure out the difference between that, and work which is actually wrong.

### That's completely normal. That's a **Ranch Panel**

A Ranch Panel is an outdoor rated panel with

- optionally: meter pan
- Main breaker typically 200A
- 4-8 breaker spaces for breakers
- "Thru Lugs" for carrying the full power onward to a subpanel, where most of the branch circuit breakers will actually live.

The idea is that if you have a ranch, you get your power out at a pole, then distribute power to the shop, shed, barn, well house, and to the house proper.  The outbuildings only need limited amps, but the house gets the whole shot.

The large enclosure is to provide for wire bending space, since you'll have 2 sets of 200A wires in there, as well as up to 4 sets of also-heavy subpanel feeder.

Since they are on the same building, *current* code does not require a main breaker in the interior panel.

### What's up with that house?

Well first, you're here asking about spaces. Second, the furnace contractor went to the trouble of putting a subpanel in the laundry room and they only did that for 2 reasons: a) the furnace is very far from the main subpanel and they wanted to use inexpensive #1 feeder for the long haul; or b) the main subpanel was out of breaker spaces *before they even installed **the furnace***.

The ranch panel, was someone else either a) also running out of breaker spaces, and that was their solution; or b) the 30-space panel is a split-bus panel (a 12-space area at one end has a breaker that cuts the other 18 spaces), and that is obsolete and dangerous, and a Ranch Panel is a great way to fix that.

So the fool here is either the one who specified a 30-space "main" subpanel for an all-electric home ... though, if the panel is Split Bus this can be forgiven, as 40-space split-bus panels didn't really exist.   Or, the one who specified a *what, 8-space?* panel for the furnace subpanel, callously thinking of only their own needs.  Spaces are laughably cheap, and you'll be pretty mad when you find out the cost differential to both choices... we're talking "a pizza".

I know you're disliking the Ranch Panel, but actually the person who picked the Ranch Panel made the right call.  They only make 'em up to 8 spaces but that's the fault of manufacturers not the installer.

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing answer and kind of spot on.  Despite being located in a very urban area, at the time the house was built it would have been considered remote.  New construction is zero lot lines and minimal yards were we have a full acre.

Comment: My novice "fixing things" were rewiring/replacing GFI outlets that were not installed correctly.  I feel I did as I actually connected the ground wire (which they did not), and tested using a GFI tester.  And I paid a licensed electrician to properly wire the dryer outlet which kind of freaked him out in how it was wired previously.